# overlaying 2 plots from different sized dataset with legends using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay, legend

I have 2 datasets, with different size. How do I simply plot them and have each with a different color and a legend? 
So in this case, the legend would be count1, count2, and the legend title is something I choose, let's say: mylegend. What do I need to change or add to the following commands?

```
x <- data.frame(Q=1:10, count1=21:30)
y <- data.frame(Q=seq(1,10,0.5), count2=seq(11,20, 0.5))
ggplot() + geom_line(data=x, aes(x=Q, y=count1)) + geom_point(data=y, aes(x=Q, y=count2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution is to combine your data in the same data.frame, then set the aesthetics (`aes`) in ggplot.

Here is one way you can combine everything:

```
df <- data.frame(Q = c(x$Q, y$Q), 
             count = c(x$count1, y$count2),
             type = c(rep("count1", 10), rep("count2", 19))
             )
```

But you can also use commands like `rbind()` or `melt()` (from the `reshape2` library).

With the data combined into one data.frame:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Q, y=count, colour=type)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + 
   scale_colour_discrete(name="mylegend")
```

This is a basic example, and I highly recommend Hadley Wickham's [ggplot2 book](http://ggplot2.org/book/), as well just searching google (Stack Overflow, R Cookbook, etc) for solutions to specific plotting problems or more ways to customize your plots.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Oshun. Is there anyway I can change the legend (count1, count2) to something else say,  a custom text, plot1, plot2?

Comment: Yes, there are several ways depending on your goal.  For example, you can set more properties in `scale_colour_discrete()`.  It's not worth covering the different solutions in an answer comment.  You can google "ggplot legends" for some examples.